# Trying to overfit in GRU characters RNN

Tags: python, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I have a GRU network, which is manually built (i.e. no `nn.GRU`) with 2 vertical layers, 128-dim hidden layer, and sequence length of 64 chars.

I'm trying to overfit a small corpus taken out of Shakespeare:

[image]

I ran training for 500+ epochs, and after every 25 epochs I generate a sample with (very low temperature) by giving only the first letter "B". At first it's gibberish, but at the end it does get close to the actual text. The first version was:

[image]

This was without passing the hidden state between batches. I thought maybe this was my problem, so I passed the hidden state, detached, between batches. But I still don't get perfect overfit, and it actually seems to worsen it:

[image]

Here's how I implemented the GRU:

```
for i in range(self.n_layers):
    layer_input = layer_middle
    layer_middle = torch.zeros((batch_size, seq_len, self.h_dim))
    params = self.layer_params[i]
    for j in range(seq_len):
        x = layer_input[:, j, :].to(torch.device('cuda'))
        z = F.sigmoid(params['W1'](x) + params['W2'](layer_states[i]))
        r = F.sigmoid(params['W3'](x) + params['W4'](layer_states[i]))
        g = F.tanh(params['W5'](x) + params['W6'](r*layer_states[i]))
        layer_states[i] = z*layer_states[i] + (1-z)*g
        layer_middle[:, j, :] = layer_states[i]
    layer_middle = nn.Dropout(self.dropout)(layer_middle)
layer_output = torch.zeros((batch_size, seq_len, self.out_dim))
for j in range(seq_len):
    x = layer_middle[:, j, :].to(torch.device('cuda'))
    layer_output[:, j, :] = self.layer_params[-1]['W7'](x)
```

The params are `nn.Linear` with the correct shapes.

Any idea what might prevent me from overfitting to this tiny corpus??

Comment: So the problem seems to be that I passed the hidden vector between epochs, which was bad. It screwed up the training. And also made it reach 100%, while the generator, which didn't get a hidden state, but started from scratch, didn't manage to get the same strings.